# How to delete objects from array using LINQ

Tags: .net, arrays, linq

I have an array of objects of type A:
`A[] ar`.
And a list of integers:
`List<int> indexes`.

How can I delete from the `ar` all objects with indexes in the `indexes`, using LINQ?
I.e. I need a new (smaller) array without the objects that their indexes are in `indexes`. Using LINQ.

Is the order of the remained objects will be the same as before the deletion?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to get new Array as a result? Arrays are immutable, you only can set NULL instead of reference to an object

Comment: @opewix It's not enough for me just to set null, I need a new (smaller) array without the objects that their indexes are in "indexes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify an array only the elements it contains.

But you can easily create a replacement array:

```
myArray = myArray.Where(x => x.KeepThisElement).ToArray();
```

With LINQ to Objects (which you'll be using in this case) there in an overload of `Where` that passes the current index to the predicate:

```
myArray = myArray.Where((x, idx) => !indexes.Conatins(idx)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is the order of the remained objects will be the same as before the deletion? Thank you.

Comment: @Ilan Yes, the input enumerable is processed in order.

Answer (score 1):

This may look odd, but it does what you want (it's not a LINQ):

```
var filtered = new List<A>();
for (var i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
{
    if (indexes.Contains(i))
        continue;

    filtered.Add(ar[i]]);
}

var ar = filtered.ToArray();
```

If your integer list is very big, consider to use `HashSet<int>` instead of list to get more performance

Comment: @openwix Thanks.. The non-linq version is indeed quite simple. But I'd like to do the same thing using LINQ query. If it's possible, of course.